# ffmpegで動画と音声を結合するときに先頭に無音を追加するには

Tags: android, ffmpeg

androidでffmpegで以下のコマンドを実行して動画に音声を結合しています。

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i movie.mp4 -i bgm.aac -vcodec copy -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4
```

その際に、動画の先頭から３秒たってから音声がスタートするようにしたいのですが方法がわかりません。最初から音声の先頭に3秒無音を追加したものを準備すればよいのですが、条件によって、無音あり無しを切り替える為、2種類を準備するのは避けたいです。

ご教授をよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `-itsoffset` オプションが使えるかもしれません。`ffmpeg ... -i movie.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:03 -i bgm.aac ...`

Comment: -itsoffset を試してみましたが、ダメでした。音声は先頭から結合されました。

Comment: `-itsoffset` と `-acodec copy` を併用すると delay が効かない様です。そこで、`ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:03 -i bgm.aac -vcodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -async 1 -strict -2 out.mp4` としたところ、3秒後から音声の再生が開始される様になりました。`-async 1` で、audio stream の offset の値を記録してくれるのだそうです。また、AAC の場合は `-strict -2` を指定する必要があるとの事です。

Comment: 3秒後から音声が再生されました。とても助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @argus 既に3票入っている質問ですし、正式な回答の形式にしてもらった方が他の人の役に立つ質疑応答となると思います。

Answer (score 2):

`-itsoffset` を使うと良いですが、これを `-acodec copy` と併用すると delay が効かないようです。そこで

```
ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:03 -i bgm.aac -vcodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -async 1 -strict -2 out.mp4
```

としたところ、3秒後から音声の再生が開始される様になりました。`-async 1` で、audio stream の offset の値を記録してくれるのだそうです。また、AAC の場合は `-strict -2` を指定する必要があるとの事です。

-- [user9156 さんのコメントより](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18161/ffmpeg%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E3%81%A8%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%82%92%E7%B5%90%E5%90%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%E5%85%88%E9%A0%AD%E3%81%AB%E7%84%A1%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF#comment16805_18161)